# Save instead of saveAs using excel activeX

Tags: javascript, excel, activex

I am using `javascript` and `activeX` to save and edit data of an excel document. So far everything works. But now i would like to write a new version where I can update a specific cell and keep the other cells as they where.

Here is the code i am using:

```
function Write() {
    var Excel, Book; // Declare the variables
    Excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application"); // Create the Excel application object.
    Excel.Visible = false; // Make Excel invisible.
    Book = Excel.Workbooks.Add() // Create a new work book.


    Book.ActiveSheet.Cells(1,1).Value = document.A1.value;

    Book.SaveAs("G:/whiteboard.xls");  
    Excel.Quit(); // Close Excel with the Quit method on the Application object.
    alert("Uppgifter sparade");
   }
```

And I want to save, instead of saveAs.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think it's possible in the context - in any case you should save a new book as file to any location, not just simply save: any application will ask you to specify the filepath on 1st save.

Comment: Either interactive Excel or  Excel VBA  doesn't allow to save a new workbook, because it creates a new file like a temporary file, so you have to specify a path and a name. So ActiveX also doesn't allow it.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone still looking for this. 
Use `excelObj.ActiveWorkbook.Save();` to save the Excel file.
Here is an example.

```
function saveExcel() {

  var excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");  
  excel.Visible = false;
  var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");


  var path = "file:\\\\C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\TestFile.xls";
  var excel_file = excel.Workbooks.Open(path); 
  var excel_sheet = excel_file.Worksheets(1); 

  //Editing all cells from Row 6 to 10 and Column 1 to 5
  for (var row = 6; row <=10; row++) {
    for (var col = 1; col <=5 ; col++) {
        excel_sheet.Cells(row,col).Value = "Setting New Cell Data"; 
      };
  };
  //Save Excel    
  excel.ActiveWorkbook.Save();

  alert("Excel Saved!");
  //showing excel are editing is done.
  excel.Visible = true;
  excel = null;
  excel_file = null;

};
```